# Activity não retorna a view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Estou tentando compilar porém não esta dando, meu layoute esta assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#F9F9F9" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DRAGÃO"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_3_material"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Em meu activity eu fiz assim:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;

@EActivity(R.layout.activity_comentarios)
public class ComentariosActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

}
```

Tentei remover a linha

> @EActivity(R.layout.activity_comentarios)

funcionou porém quando entro na tela ela fica toda laranja como na imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso deveria esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No `Logcat` aparece este error:

> Error:(7, 1) error: The AndroidManifest.xml file contains the original component, and not the AndroidAnnotations generated component. Please register ComentariosActivity_ instead of ComentariosActivity

No meu AndroidManifest esta assim:

```
<activity android:name=".ComentariosActivity"
       android:label="Comentarios"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, bastou alterar minha classe para:

```
package com.fomedemais.FomeDemais;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;


public class ComentariosActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comentarios);
    }
}
```

E ainda adicionar no `AndroidManifest` como a resposta do meu amigo @sparkss

```
<activity android:name=".ComentariosActivity_"
  android:label="Comentarios"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 3):

o próprio Error já da a solução

> Please register ComentariosActivity_ instead of ComentariosActivity

, no AndroidManifest coloque:

```
<activity android:name=".ComentariosActivity_"
   android:label="Comentarios"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: Tentei fazer isto e mesmo assim as telas não foi chamada